# Running Node.JS with IIS. Can’t connect to site from other computers, but site runs on local server

Tags: node.js, iis

I am trying to host a Node.JS app on a server that also has IIS running on it. I can open the site in the server browser. As you can see i have the website iisnode running in the browser and it is added in the IIS manager

[image]

However, i can not access this site from a different computer using ServerURL/siteName. I just get this error:
[image]

What could i be doing wrong? It works locally so i must be close to having it working. I can access other sites hosted on this server so i know the issue is with this app specifically.

Comment: Start isolating the problem. Can you browse a static html file? Are you using the correct host name? Do you need to use an IP address instead?

Comment: Because the site bindings you configured do not accept external traffic, https://www.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html